# Viewing a fax in Tif or PDF?

Tags: iphone, ios

We are consuming a web service that returns a fax document in the form of a PDF or a Tif file.  The goal here is to be able to view the fax which could be multipage allowing the user to click through the various fax "pages"

The challenge we are having is that the fax can either return a PDF or a Tif file. We are getting one large PDF or one large Tif file even though the fax could be several pages long.

What file format is a better choice for us to be able to :

1). Allow the user to view it in a multi-page format? That is what is better to deal with in terms of pagination?

2). What is a better user interface choice?

3). How would we get about even paginating either one of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a PDF everytime. They can be multi page docs (as long as they have been created that way), they are a lot smaller than tiff's and there's plenty of good readers out there.

Answer (score 1):

I've create my own solution for viewing mutlipage TIFF files: [NSTiffSplitter](https://github.com/Sharrp/NSTiffSplitter).
You can find it on [github](https://github.com/Sharrp/NSTiffSplitter).

```
NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example" ofType:@"tiff"];
NSTiffSplitter* splitter = [[NSTiffSplitter alloc] initWithPathToImage:pathToImage];
UIImage *page = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[splitter dataForImage:page]];
yourImageView.image = page;
[page release];
```